# How to magento1 compatible with php 7.4?

Tags: magento-1.9, php, magento-1.8, php-7.4

Please Help me guyz

can we run magento1 using php 7.4?

Please let me know (magento expert*).

Thanks,

Comment: This plugin was developed for something like that-
https://github.com/Inchoo/Inchoo_PHP7

Comment: Sorry But i can't understant, what i have to do can you explain me well about it.

Comment: Yes We can run, Recently I fixed my client's this same issue, his website was down since weeks due to auto upgrade on php 7.4, keep in mind only experts can do this if you are beginners stay away.

Thanks

Comment: Can you guide me plz how did you solve this, any documentation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento 1.9.x is actually compatible with PHP 7.4 if you've applied the patches that enable PHP 7.2 compatibility.